# Amazon s3 policy does not work with nginx ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy, policy

I have created a policy for my private bucket in order to allow only one ip to access the content. When I set it to my ip everything works fine but when I set it to the ip of the machine that my nginx as a reverse proxy runs is not working.Any ides?

This is my policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "instance running nginx public ip"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and the nginx configuration for the bucket:

```
 location   /privateproxy  {
  set $s3_bucket        'bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com';
  set $url_full         '$1';

  proxy_http_version     1.1;
  proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
  proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
  proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
  proxy_buffering        off;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  resolver               8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout       10s;

  proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket/$url_full;
```

}

I have also tried accessing like a normal reverse proxy:

```
location /privateproxy {
             proxy_pass http://bucket....eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/;
             proxy_read_timeout  30;
             proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
             proxy_ssl_verify off; 
}
```

Comment: Are you using a VPC endpoint for S3??

Comment: Are you using the public, or the private, IP address of your `nginx`-running instance in your S3 policy?

Comment: I have a VPC endpoint for the bucket and I am using the public IP in the bucket policy. I should use the private ip of the ec2 instance instead?

Comment: you should try, between amazon services, they're using private ip (at least between my ec2 and rds) the public IP is for internet facing

Comment: S3 and EC2 are run on two different networks within AWS; this is why S3 requests from your EC2 instances will go through your VPC NAT gateway (to reach S3).  Thus you might try using the public IP address of your EC2 instance in your S3 policy.

Comment: I have used both public and private but it doesn't seem to work. I will give it a try with both IPs again.

Comment: You might also try using the IP address of your VPC NAT gateway instance (public and private, just to test/experiment).

Comment: I am using every possible IP address in the policy. I also added the range /0 at the end of every IP so that I am sure it will be ok.
The nginx configuration must be wrong.